# What precisely does DEPTH_LIMIT refer to? Is the current depth referencable?

Tags: python, scrapy

Scrapy indicates it has a [`DEPTH_LIMIT` setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#depth-limit), but doesn't specifically say what it considers 'depth'. In terms of scraping pages, I've seen 'depth' refer to 'depth of the url', or `http://somedomain.com/this/is/a/depth/six/url`, where the page that is requested by that URL has a depth of 'six', because it's six segments in. `http://somedomain.com` would be depth zero.

On the other hand, when we consider scraping in terms of trees, depth would more likely refer to how far you are from the starting location. Thus, if I feed it a starting url of `http://somedomain.com/start/here`, that is depth zero, and any link found on that response would be depth one.

Does Scrapy use one of these definitions? If so which one? If it is the latter one (which seems the more logical), is there any way to get that depth information, either when you're processing the response in the crawler or when you're post-processing it as an item in the pipeline?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm making this up or not, but I think it's in the meta data... (been ages since I've used scrapy) - does `response.meta['depth']` do anything? And yes, I think it's the later because of the way scrapy traverses the tree... (at least I think it's DFS... but it's been a while...)

Comment: @JonClements Yes! That is exactly the information I needed and proves the theory. Thanks! If you want to file an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Okay.. done... could be useful others... hopefully I haven't made it up - like I said - it's been a while...

Comment: @JonClements Unless I'm deeply misunderstanding something the data from that meta dict shows that understanding to be correct. But I'll be working with it for a bit, so if I run into something odd I'll mention it.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know either way. Was just going to have a toy around myself, but don't have scrapy installed and the projects I've used it on aren't  available without restoring from a Glacier... so... yeah :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy uses a DFS approach for traversal and the current depth can be accessed via the response meta data: `response.meta['depth']`.